# Custom sound on FireBase notification receive

Tags: android, ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-notifications

I am currently using `FireBase` `PushNotifications` for my xamarin(cross platform) application, and i am looking for a way to play custom sound(`Alarm`) on notification receive for **both iOS and Android** apps. Plus, i need to play that sound in foreground mode **as well as in background**.